# Django_ses with boto versions above 2.1

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-ses

Im trying to send email using the send_mail call from within a django application previously I had used django_ses, but I have hit on an issue.

I know the django_ses library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ses) isn't maintained actively, though it claims to still be widely in use. I've recently upgraded the boto version on the machine to the latest (2.31) and im getting a certificate error when trying to send an email (Stack trace included below). I've confirmed that returning boto to version 2.1 stops the error, so im guessing the two are incompatable. Has anyone managed to patch around the issue?

thanks

Steve

```
>>> send_mail('Test subject', 'This is the body', 'donotreply@example.com',['someone@example.com'], fail_silently=False)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 248, in send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_ses-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/django_ses/__init__.py", line 122, in send_messages
    rate_limit = self.get_rate_limit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_ses-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/django_ses/__init__.py", line 196, in get_rate_limit
    quota_dict = self.connection.get_send_quota()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ses/connection.py", line 339, in get_send_quota
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ses/connection.py", line 101, in _make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 932, in make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 894, in _mexe
SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem wasn't a version incomparability, but where my server was located. From the experimenting I've done, django_ses doesn't play well when not on an EC2 machine. I switched to using the smtp library which drops in just as easily and im away.

https://github.com/bancek/django-smtp-ssl